# 50 people in a circle

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> $50$ fighters are standing around in a circle. Every fighter may choose
>   to fight with the person on its left or its right with equal
>   probability. One person may be chosen by two different persons and
>   another may not be chosen at all. Can you expect how many fighters
>   were not chosen? Explain.

I started trying with $4,6,8$ fighters to see if I could end up figuring out a pattern. And noticed that if $X$ represents the random variable associated with the number of people not selected then $0 \leq X \leq 25$.  Also one of the things I've noticed was that $P(n)=P(25-n)$ which may help through solving this problem. Also I know that this is an expected value probability problem, and that I have to figure out $P(X=n)$, for $n$ going from $0$ to $25$.

Unfortunately, I couldn't figure it out, so can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: If you are asked to find an expectation then you can go for $\mathbb EX=\sum_n nP(X=n)$ but make it a custom first to go for $\mathbb EX$ directly in the sense that you try to avoid the use of the distribution. Often that is possible and it can spare you lots of calculations.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! @drhab

Comment: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Guide**.

Number the fighters and let $X_i$ take value $1$ if fighter $i$ is not chosen and $0$ if he was chosen.

If $X$ denotes the number of fighters not chosen then:$$X=X_1+\cdots+X_{50}$$

Now find the expectation of $X$ by applying linearity of expectation and symmetry.

Comment: sorry I removed my comment because I realized that I've said something unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $X_i$ be the random variable denoting whether person $i$ is left alone. It is $1$ if person $i$ wasn't chosen by anyone, and $0$ if he / she were. Phrase your problem in terms of these $X_i$, figure out the probability distribution for each of them, and things will become simpler.